# Why does the VBA Sort Method not use the custom sort list i provided?

Tags: excel, vba

I checked the entire code step by step, all the steps work as they should. The correct CostumList Index is being used but it always sorts the rows alphabetically instead of with my costum list.

```
    Dim vCustom_Sort As Variant
    wsName.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    vCustom_Sort = Array("Direktor Gruppe/CEO", _
                    "CDO - Chief Development Officer", _
                    "CFO - Chief Financial Officer", _
                    "COO - Chief Operating Officer", _
                    "Assistenz CEO", _
                    "Holding Management Office", _
                    "Chauffeur", _
                    "Assistenz CFO", _
                    "Finanzen", _
                    "Bilanzierung", _
                    "Strategische IT", _
                    "Corporate Marketing & Communication", _
                    "Leitung Arbeitsschutz", _
                    "Arbeitsschutz", _
                    "Leitung Facility Management", _
                    "Facility Management", _
                    "Organisation, Prozesse & Privacy" _
                    )
    
    Dim customListIndex As Long
    customListIndex = Application.CustomListCount + 1
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCustom_Sort
    
    ' Find the index of the added custom list
    Dim tempList As Variant
    For i = 1 To Application.CustomListCount
        On Error Resume Next
        tempList = Application.GetCustomListContents(i)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not IsEmpty(tempList) Then
            If UBound(tempList) = UBound(vCustom_Sort) + 1 Then 'Here i had to add 1 to "UBound(vCustom_Sort)" since "vCustom_Sort" starts at 0 and "tempList" starts at 1
                Dim listMatch As Boolean
                listMatch = True
                For j = LBound(vCustom_Sort) To UBound(vCustom_Sort)
                    If tempList(j + 1) <> vCustom_Sort(j) Then 'Here again I had to add 1 to the variable "j" because "tempList" starts at 1 and "vCustom_Sort" starts at 0, and otherwise the loop would return an error since "j" starts at 0 and the "tempList" wouldn't have index 0
                        listMatch = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If listMatch Then
                    customListIndex = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    wsName.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    With wsName.Range("A3", wsName.Cells(lastRow(wsName), lastColumn(wsName)))
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=wsName.Range("B3:B" & lastRow(wsName)), Order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                    Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                    OrderCustom:=customListIndex

    End With
    wsName.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

It sorts column B in the following way:

[Column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv4n8.png)

I know not all values in column B correspond to the value in the costum sort list (for example "CDO Chief Development Officer" is slightly different in the sort list so it wouldn't match), but I didn't focus on that part since as you can see even the matching values don't sort as they should. It sorts alphabetically.

I tried to check every part of the code. I checked if the Range for the Sort method is correct and if the key is referencing the correct column and range. I checked if the "lastRow" and "lastColumn" functions return the correct value and they always do. I also checked if there is an issue with the "wsName" variable, but there isn't, but for reference here it is:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
'Worksheets are added
wsName = wb.Sheets("Holding Management")
```

I hope I explained my problem well enough, sorry if I didn't, this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow :)

**------------------------**
**Solution:**
I tried many different approaches but ultimately the only one that worked was one with a "Helper Column"

Here is the code:

```
        ' Add a helper column with numeric values based on the custom list
        Dim helperColumn As Long
        helperColumn = lastColumn(wsName) + 1 'lastColumn is a function that returns an integer, representing the last Column in that worksheet
        
        wsName.Cells(3, helperColumn).Value = "Helper Column"
        For j = LBound(customList) To UBound(customList)
            For i = 4 To lastRow(wsName)
                If LCase(wsName.Cells(i, "B").Value) = LCase(customList(j)) Then
                    wsName.Cells(i, helperColumn).Value = j
                End If
            Next i
        Next j
    
        ' Sort the range based on the helper column
        With wsName.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=wsName.Range(wsName.Cells(3, helperColumn), wsName.Cells(lastRow(wsName), helperColumn)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=Join(customList, Chr(1)), DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange sortRange
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    
        ' Clean up: remove the helper column
        wsName.Columns(helperColumn).Clear
```

Comment: Don't you need `SortOn:=xlSortOnValues` to use the list?

Comment: I tried this, but it returns an error and it seems like it's not needed. Since I use `OrderCustom:=customListIndex` the code seems to know that it needs to sort on values. At least from what I've tried and researched. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: "the code seems to know that it needs to sort on values" - except you stated it was sorting alphabetically
"but it returns an error " - WHAT error?
"it seems like it's not needed." - I think it is

Comment: @CHill60 Sorry for not providing enough information. In the meantime I tried different approaches, and I settled on the helper column. This works perfectly. I edited the original post and added the solution.